# Need help with power supply in my project

Tags: power-supply, batteries, power-electronics, arduino-uno, split

I am a mechanical engineer.
I need some help with my project
I am building a water sampling device that has 11 solenoid valves and a vacuum pump to distribute water to various containers on the device. 
I have a single battery, and a microprocessor (Arduino). 
I am not sure how to do the wiring here. 
How can I supply power to all the 11 solenoid valves and still control the valves using an Arduino. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: need far more information, could you provide things like the voltage and current rating of the solenoids, same for the vacuum pump, the voltage and capacity of the battery,

Comment: A schema of how you need it to operate (or how you might *want* it to operate) would be helpful apart from the specifics of the solenoid valves and vacuum pump.

Comment: Thanks for the reply’s so far. The solenoids are 12v 1A. I haven’t really selected any battery or a pump. Water has to be stored into different bottles but only 1 bottle is being filled at a time. There is a main pipe to which all the solenoids are connected. All the solenoids are in a closed position by default. The Arduino opens the required valve.

Comment: All that information belongs in the question, not buried in the comments. Please [edit].

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you would need to use a battery and not a mains operated 12V DC power supply.

An unregulated 12V DC 3A power supply should suffice for the solenoids, considering that you require to energise only one solenoid valve at a time.

You would also require three 4 channel relay modules, to be driven by the Arduino outputs.

[image]

The wiring for one solenoid valve is shown. The others would be wired identically.